# insert the "<?!= include ?>" clause into google html-app file by using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, svg, google-apps

i'd like to insert dinamically (by jquery) an html file into a google html-app main file via the `<?!= include("filename"); ?>` instruction, i mean something like [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascript); being more specific my purpose is to populate an empty `<ul>` with some svg files saved into the project as portion of html.

i tried:

```
$("#options-list").append("<li><?!= include(\"filename\"); ?></li>");
$("#options-list").append("<li>").append(`<?!= include(\"filename\`);
```

and other similar combinations but always got a comment:

```
<ul id="options-list">
<li></li>
<!-- ?!= include("filename"); -->
</ul>
```

i also tried replacing "<" with "`&lt;`" and so on ... but no success, end up with a text between `<li></li>`.

is it possible to do that?
if possible, is it a matter of escaping "particular" characters or something totally different?

thanks in advance

Comment: I can get a non-comment in if I do something like `$("#options-list li")[0].textContent = "<?!= include(\"filename\"); ?>";`, but it appears the documentation recommends against this sort of loading via templates anyway in favor of an asynchronous google.script.run call instead (though I don't know the specifics or your project, of course).

Comment: hi max, thanks for your reply.

your solution doesn't insert a comment but a text, so in the end i get is a list of `<?!= include(\"filename\");  ?>` while i'd like to show some svg. briefly this part of project is a menu which opens a submenu, so i need to fill the `ul` according to the key selected.

actually i already achieved it by loading the svg files from a folder in my google drive space but looks a bit of slow.

as to use server side script i don't know if it's workable (i'm not really mastering web things, this project is just for my personal usage); if so please advice. thanks

Comment: I suspected that you would get just a text list, since it's presumably running that part of the jQuery after the page (including any server side scripting) has loaded. Hence why the documentation you linked to in your question recommends using the google.script.run call (which would process the list-populating function as soon as the data it called were loaded).

Comment: got it max.actually the point was what you mentioned, i had to call the function through google.script.run and not via scriplet (i got it after going through documentation more carefully); thanks max